# How to prepare JSON format export from Pandas dataframe for Apexcharts?

Tags: python, json, dataframe, apexcharts

As an input I have pandas dataframe with few numeric columns, which I would like to use as a source in Apexcharts which reads data from JSON. Can you please help me with a right format of JSON and how to read it from javascript to display selected series in Apexcharts?

Test Data from python pandas:

```
planStartAmount = 1000
plan1Perc = 0.015   
plan2Perc = 0.02    

date_pattern = pd.date_range(start='2022-12-01', end='2022-12-20')
date_pattern = pd.DataFrame({"Date": date_pattern})
date_pattern['Weekday'] = date_pattern['Date'].dt.dayofweek + 1  

date_pattern = date_pattern.reset_index(drop=True)
date_pattern['PlanDayNumber'] = date_pattern.index + 1 

for index, row in date_pattern.iterrows():
    if index == 0:
        #print('index je nula')
        #date_pattern['BalanceStartOfDay'][index] = plan1StartAmount
        date_pattern.loc[index,'Plan1BalanceStartOfDay'] = planStartAmount
        date_pattern.loc[index,'Plan2BalanceStartOfDay'] = planStartAmount
    else:
        #date_pattern['BalanceStartOfDay'][index] = date_pattern['BalanceEndOfDay'][index-1]
        date_pattern.loc[index,'Plan1BalanceStartOfDay'] = date_pattern.loc[index-1,'Plan1BalanceEndOfDay']
        date_pattern.loc[index,'Plan2BalanceStartOfDay'] = date_pattern.loc[index-1,'Plan2BalanceEndOfDay']
        
    date_pattern.loc[index,'Plan1BalanceDayTarget'] = round(date_pattern.loc[index,'Plan1BalanceStartOfDay'] * plan1Perc)
    date_pattern.loc[index,'Plan2BalanceDayTarget'] = round(date_pattern.loc[index,'Plan2BalanceStartOfDay'] * plan2Perc)
    
    date_pattern.loc[index,'Plan1BalanceEndOfDay'] = date_pattern.loc[index,'Plan1BalanceStartOfDay'] + date_pattern.loc[index,'Plan1BalanceDayTarget'] 
    date_pattern.loc[index,'Plan2BalanceEndOfDay'] = date_pattern.loc[index,'Plan2BalanceStartOfDay'] + date_pattern.loc[index,'Plan2BalanceDayTarget'] 
   
date_pattern = pd.DataFrame( date_pattern,
                             columns=['Date', 'PlanDayNumber', 'Plan1BalanceEndOfDay', 'Plan2BalanceEndOfDay']
                                 )

date_pattern.to_json('plans.json', orient = 'table', compression = 'infer', index = 'true')
date_pattern
```

In html, in  section I would like to create an Apexchart (or other charts) which uses columns Plan1BalanceEndOfDay and Plan2BalanceEndOfDay as a data series, and Date as a categories?

How to correctly format exported JSON file?

Code which must be modified in javascript:

```
<script>
    var options = {
      chart: {
          height: 300,
          type: 'line',
      },
      dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
      },
      series: [],
      title: {
          text: 'Ajax Example',
      },
      noData: {
        text: 'Loading...'
      },
      stroke: {
        dashArray: 2
      },
      xaxis: {
          type: 'category',
          tickPlacement: 'on',
          labels: {
            rotate: -45,
            rotateAlways: true
          }
      }   
    }
    
    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#apexcharts-line-chart"), options );
    chart.render();

    //  in order to create dynamic charts using JSON data, all you need to do is render an empty chart initially and then call the updateSeries method.
    // var url = 'data/yearly.json';
    var url = 'data/plans.json';
    
    $.getJSON(url, function(response) {
        chart.updateSeries([{
          name: 'Sales',
          data: response
        }])
      });
      
  </script>
```

resp. how to modify below code to read my JSON?

```
 <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            // Line chart
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    height: 350,
                    type: "line",
                    zoom: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                stroke: {
                    width: [5, 7, 5],
                    curve: "straight",
                    dashArray: [0, 8, 5]
                },
                series: [{
                        name: "Series 1",
                        data: [45, 52, 38, 24, 33, 26, 21, 20, 6, 8, 15, 10]
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Series 2",
                        data: [35, 41, 62, 42, 13, 18, 29, 37, 36, 51, 32, 53]
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Series 3",
                        data: [87, 57, 74, 99, 75, 38, 62, 47, 82, 56, 63, 91]
                    }
                ],
                markers: {
                    size: 0,
                    style: "hollow", // full, hollow, inverted
                },
                xaxis: {
                    categories: ["01 Jan", "02 Jan", "03 Jan", "04 Jan", "05 Jan", "06 Jan", "07 Jan", "08 Jan", "09 Jan", "10 Jan", "11 Jan", "12 Jan"],
                },
                tooltip: {
                    y: [{
                        title: {
                            formatter: function(val) {
                                return val + " (mins)"
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        title: {
                            formatter: function(val) {
                                return val + " per session"
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        title: {
                            formatter: function(val) {
                                return val;
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                },
                grid: {
                    borderColor: "#f1f1f1",
                }
            }
            var chart = new ApexCharts(
                document.querySelector("#apexcharts-line"),
                options
            );
            chart.render();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can anyone help please with above question?